# How to use HList to validate input?

Tags: scala, shapeless

I'm using Shapeless 2.0 and I'm trying to use HList to validate input — with as much of the checking as possible performed at compile time.

I have an HList `spec` that specifies what type of input I'm expecting (the types should be checked at compile time) and may also include a runtime check to be performed (e.g., to test if a number is even or odd).

Consider the following specification:

```
trait Pred[T] { def apply(t: T): Boolean }
val IsString = new Pred[String] { def apply(s: String) = true }
val IsOddNumber = new Pred[Int] { def apply(n: Int) = n % 2 != 0 }
val IsEvenNumber = new Pred[Int] { def apply(n: Int) = n % 2 == 0 }
val spec = IsEvenNumber :: IsString :: IsString :: IsOddNumber :: HNil
```

And various sample inputs:

```
val goodInput = 4 :: "foo" :: "" :: 5 :: HNil
val badInput = 4 :: "foo" :: "" :: 4 :: HNil
val malformedInput = 4 :: 5 :: "" :: 6 :: HNil
```

How would I make a function where I can effectively do:

```
input.zip(spec).forall{case (input, test) => test(input)}
```

So the following would happen:

```
f(spec, goodInput) // true
f(spec, badInput) // false
f(spec, malformedInput) // Does not compile
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

These answers by Travis Brown include most of what's needed:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/20452151/86485
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/21005225/86485

but it took me a long time to find those answers, figure out that they were applicable to your problem, and work out the details of combining and applying them.

And I think your question adds value because it demonstrates how this can come up when solving a practical problem, namely validating input. I'll also try to add value below by showing a complete solution including demo code and tests.

Here's generic code for doing the checking:

```
object Checker {
  import shapeless._, poly._, ops.hlist._
  object check extends Poly1 {
    implicit def apply[T] = at[(T, Pred[T])]{
      case (t, pred) => pred(t)
    }
  }
  def apply[L1 <: HList, L2 <: HList, N <: Nat, Z <: HList, M <: HList](input: L1, spec: L2)(
    implicit zipper: Zip.Aux[L1 :: L2 :: HNil, Z],
             mapper: Mapper.Aux[check.type, Z, M],
             length1: Length.Aux[L1, N],
             length2: Length.Aux[L2, N],
             toList: ToList[M, Boolean]) =
    input.zip(spec)
      .map(check)
      .toList
      .forall(Predef.identity)
}
```

And here's the demo usage code:

```
object Frank {
  import shapeless._, nat._
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val IsString     = new Pred[String] { def apply(s: String) = true       }
    val IsOddNumber  = new Pred[Int]    { def apply(n: Int)    = n % 2 != 0 }
    val IsEvenNumber = new Pred[Int]    { def apply(n: Int)    = n % 2 == 0 }
    val spec = IsEvenNumber :: IsString :: IsString :: IsOddNumber :: HNil
    val goodInput       = 4 :: "foo" :: "" :: 5 :: HNil
    val badInput        = 4 :: "foo" :: "" :: 4 :: HNil
    val malformedInput1 = 4 :: 5     :: "" :: 6 :: HNil
    val malformedInput2 = 4 :: "foo" :: "" :: HNil
    val malformedInput3 = 4 :: "foo" :: "" :: 5 :: 6 :: HNil
    println(Checker(goodInput, spec))
    println(Checker(badInput, spec))
    import shapeless.test.illTyped
    illTyped("Checker(malformedInput1, spec)")
    illTyped("Checker(malformedInput2, spec)")
    illTyped("Checker(malformedInput3, spec)")
  }
}

/*
results when run:
[info] Running Frank
true
false
*/
```

Note the use of `illTyped` to verify that code that should not compile, does not.

Some side notes:

- I initially went down a long garden path with this, where I thought it would be important for the polymorphic function `check` to have a more specific type than `Poly1`, to represent that the return type in all cases is Boolean. So I kept trying to make it work with `extends (Id ~>> Boolean)`. But it turns out not to matter whether the type system knows that the result type is the Boolean in every case. It's enough that the only case that we actually have has the right type. `extends Poly1` is a marvelous thing.
- Value-level `zip` traditionally allows unequal lengths and discards the extras. Miles followed suit in Shapeless's type-level `zip`, so we need a separate check for equal lengths.
- It's a bit sad that the call site has to `import nat._`, otherwise the implicit instances for `Length` aren't found. One would prefer these details to be handled at the definition site. ([A fix is pending.](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/pull/85))
- If I understand correctly, I can't use `Mapped` (a la https://stackoverflow.com/a/21005225/86485) to avoid the length check, because some of my checkers (e.g. `IsString`) have singleton types that are more specific than just e.g. `Pred[String]`.
- Travis points out that `Pred` could extend `T => Boolean`, making it possible to use `ZipApply`. I leave following this suggestion as an exercise for the reader :-)

Comment: This is really impressive, I'm still getting to grips with Shapeless and posts like this help a lot, thanks.

I was playing around with this, and deleted the implicits to Check.apply, expecting Checker(malformedInput, spec) to compile. It does, however Checker(badInput, spec) then returns true. Any idea why? I can't work that out. I was expecting removing the implicits just to remove some of the type safety, rather than change the runtime behaviour.

Comment: As Miles [just pointed out on Twitter](https://twitter.com/milessabin/status/447051802199199744), you can now write `(goodInput zipWith spec)(check)`—watch out for the fact that this doesn't require the lengths to match, though.

Comment: @NoelM: Sounds like https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/pull/56 . Try it in the latest snapshot?

Comment: @TravisBrown: Oops, my original code didn't require the lengths to match, either. Now updated with fix (using `Length`; added note about why not `Mapped`).